# How do I get rid off error on adding Foreign Key to a table which contains data

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints, alter-table

I am using the below written query to add a foreign key to an Existing Field with data:

```
 ALTER TABLE ServiceDetails
 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_ServiceDetails
 FOREIGN KEY (OCF_ID)
 REFERENCES OCF_Commerce(OCF_Internal_ID);
```

But I am getting an error after executing the query. What am I missing?

The error message is:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_ServiceDetails". The conflict occurred in database "TrulyDB", table "dbo.OCF_Commerce", column 'OCF_Internal_ID'.

Comment: Check whether your ServiceDetails Table has all the OCF_ID of OCF_Internal_ID in OCF_Commerce Tbale

Comment: data for FK and PK do not match , for example there is FK of 194 but there is no PK of 194 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have inconsistent data in your tables
try running

```
select *
from ServiceDetails 
where OCF_ID not in (select OCF_Internal_ID from OCF_Commerce)
```

This will output all rows with ID absent in master table